# I am getting only first header element style color as green, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here out of all 4 header element I am getting only first header element to be printed as green

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  var tag = document.createElement("h1");
  var text = document.createTextNode(i + " Tutorix is the best e-learning platform");
  tag.appendChild(text);
  var element = document.getElementById("new");
  element.appendChild(tag);
  let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
  h1.setAttribute("style", "color: green;");
  // console.log("Hi there"+h1);
}
```

```html
<div id="new">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am getting only first header element style color as green, why?

Because [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) only selects the **first** element that matches.

If you want to set the color of the element you just added, use the reference you already have to the element: `tag`. (Side note: `tag` is an odd name for that variable, because it doesn't contain or refer to a tag, it refers to an *element*.)

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  var tag = document.createElement("h1");
  var text = document.createTextNode(i + " Tutorix is the best e-learning platform");
  tag.appendChild(text);
  var element = document.getElementById("new");
  element.appendChild(tag);
  tag.setAttribute("style", "color: green;");
}
```

```html
<div id="new">

</div>
```

---

Side note: In general, it's cleaner to assign to properties on the style object rather than setting the `style` attribute:

```
tag.style.color = "green";
```

They do different things (the above *only* sets the `color` to green without changing anything else; setting the `style` attribute completely replaces all inline styles for the element with what you provide).

Answer (score 0):

The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
[Query Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.
[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: True, but _only_ changing `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` will [cause different problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return).

Comment: Yes thats true @Ivar i am just trying to give the context that why only first was getting style applied